# ASP.NET how to declare a session that only exist in single page

Tags: asp.net

just as the title mentioned, how to declare a session that only exist in a single page. that mean when I go to another page, the session will clear.

Comment: Session variables are used to store value that are available across all the pages in the current session. Why do you want to use session variable and that too in a single page, you can achieve it using a global variable ?

Comment: You can use the Viewstate/hidden variable for this

Comment: You probably need to state if this is MVC or Web forms, since the techniques used will be different.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ViewState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx), ASP.NET pages provide the ViewState property as a built-in structure for automatically storing values between multiple requests for the same page.

To set one variable in View State,

```
ViewState["Variable"]=YourValue;
```

To get information from View State

```
string myVar=ViewState["Variable"];
```

Comment: but viewState need to serialize control. because I need used it to store control and datatable. I think viewState is not allow me to store datatable and control.

Answer (score 1):

`ViewState` is page specific, so this would be your best choice for **Web Form** applications.  [Understanding ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) will be a good start.

If you are using **MVC**, then you could use `Hidden Variables`, `ViewBag` etc.  [ViewBag, ViewData explained](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476967/WhatplusisplusViewData-2cplusViewBagplusandplusTem).

It might also be worth explaining what you want to achieve, as there might be better options.

Answer (score 0):

As Bibhu said, Session variables are across all pages.

However, within that, you can make a session variable called `Session["YourPageIDorName"] = new Dictionary()` and use it to store per page variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using web forms the ideal solution would be to use view state only as it is page specific and won't be accessible on any other page. Although there is a method to disable session on pages by setting:

EnableSessionState = false

on the page directive (on aspx page). But that does not clear the session, rather it refrains the usage of session on the specific pages.

If you are using MVC then you can use tempdata to get data across a single get and post cycle. But unlike view state (in web forms), you will have to repopulate if you want to use it across another post back.

There a number of other state management techniques that you may use according to your need:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx

Hope this helps.